# circles with different color based on the values in the data using google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am reading the place names from a csv file and doing geocoding using google maps api. I am using circle icons instead of default red markers. Now i would like to know whether those circle icon can be appear in different colours based on the value in the csv data using google maps api?

for ex i will get a json response for the region_name and average as

```
$.getJSON(json_link,
                            function (data) {
                                //console.log(data)
                                // response(data);
                                var place_names = [];
                                var average_value = [];
                                for (i=0; i<data.rows.length; i++) {
                                    unique = data.rows[i].region_name;
                                    place_names.push(unique);
                                }
                                for (i=0; i<data.rows.length; i++) {
                                    average_values = data.rows[i].average;
                                    average_value.push(average_values);
                                }
                                console.log(place_names);
                                console.log(average_value);
```

And those region_names will have corresponding average values which is stored in average_value array. For those particular region_names with their corresponding average_value, i should get the color of the circle icon vary.

And my geocoding part is

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                                var address = place_names;
                                var average = average_value;
                                var color = 'blue'; 
                                console.log(address);
                                for (i=0; i<=address.length; i++) {
                                    if (average[i] >  0 && average[i] < 30) {
                                        color = 'red';
                                    } 
                                    else {
                                        color = 'green';
                                    }
                                    geocoder.geocode({'address': address[i]}, function(results, status) {
                                        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                                    icon: {
                                                        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                                                        scale: 10,
                                                        fillColor: color,
                                                        fillOpacity: 0.5,
                                                        strokeWeight: 1
                                                    },
                                                    map: map
                                                });

                                        } else {
                                            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
```

Comment: For draw the circle you need the coord (lat,lng) fo the center, the radius and for the color  need  value mapped to the color ... show also this info...please...

Comment: Well, is it not possible using google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE?

Comment: Yes is possible but the problem related to the coords of the center of each circle and the the color still the same...

Comment: It is not circle. I am creating a marker and just changing the icon of the marker alone to a circle using google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE.  I had added my geocoding code too for your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code, causing it to run past the end of the array:

```
for (i = 0; i <= address.length; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
```

One way to solve your issue with colored icons is to use function closure to associate the color with the callback of the geocoder:

```
function geocode(address, color, geocoder, map) {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                icon: {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    scale: 10,
                    fillColor: color,
                    fillOpacity: 0.5,
                    strokeWeight: 1
                },
                map: map
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);

        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gsdvtave/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var place_names = ["New York, NY", "Newark, NJ", "Boston, MA", "Baltimore, MD"];
var average_value = [5, 40, 20, 60];
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = place_names;
  var average = average_value;
  var color = 'blue';
  console.log(address);
  for (i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
    if (average[i] > 0 && average[i] < 30) {
      color = 'red';
    } else {
      color = 'green';
    }
    geocode(address[i], color, geocoder, map);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function geocode(address, color, geocoder, map) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        icon: {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          scale: 10,
          fillColor: color,
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
          strokeWeight: 1
        },
        map: map
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sometinghs like this

```
     var address = place_names;
     var average =  average_value;
     var color = '#F00';
                            console.log(address);

                            for (i=0; i<=address.length; i++) {

                                 if (average[i] >  your_lower_limit && average[i] < you_upper_limit) {
                                    color = '#0F0';
                                 }
                                // repeat for other limit and color 
                                geocoder.geocode({'address': address[i]}, function(results, status) {
                                    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                            icon: {
                                                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                                                scale: 10,
                                                fillColor: color,
                                                fillOpacity: 0.4,
                                                strokeWeight: 0.4
                                            },
                                            map: map
                                        });
```

Comment: I had edited my question based on the exact requirement.

Comment: I had tried with the above code and even i had edited my code with which i had tried. But colors doesnt change.